# How to do a parallel flatMapConcat in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream

We would like to parallelize a part of our stream keeping ordering like mapAsync does but then without Future.

Currently we have the below solution but this requires a materializer where a plain flatMapConcat does not.

```scala
def flatMapConcatParallel[In, Out](parallelism: Int)(f: In => Source[Out, _])(implicit mat: Materializer): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] = {
    // TODO there should be a better way to add parallelism that avoids a run (and the need for a materializer)
    Flow[In].mapAsync(parallelism){i =>
      f(i).runWith(Sink.head)
    }
  }
```

and

```scala
if (parallel){
  val parallelism = 4
  Flow[Batch].via(flatMapConcatParallel(parallelism)(singleRun))
} else{
  Flow[Batch].flatMapConcat(singleRun)
}
```

Any hints on how this could be implemented with existing constructs without having to go low-level (GraphStageLogic)?

```
                            ---> f() --->
--d-c-b-a--> OrderedBalance ---> f() ---> OrderedMerge --d'-c'-b'-a'--->
                            ---> f() --->
```

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
Flow[In].mapAsync(parallelism)(i => Future.successful(f(i))).flatMapConcat(identity)
```

Comment: Why did I not come up with this myself? Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You can of course also use the Future.apply method and provide it with your own ExecutionContext.

Comment: I was a bit too fast on this one. This solution parallelises the creation of the source graph but not the running of the stream.

Comment: Add ".async" to whatever stages you want to run in parallel. See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-parallelism.html#parallel-processing

Comment: Speaking in terms of the documentation I need a n-way pipeline that keeps ordering. "In those cases the Balance and Merge stages should be replaced by strict-round robing balancing and merging stages that put in and take out pancakes in a strict order."

Comment: Added small ascii visualisation to show what I need.

Comment: Sounds like all you need is what I showed. use Future.apply iso Future.successful to control where execution is done.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid going to Futures or using mapAsync (to avoid the need for materialization)

Comment: Futures do not require Materializers.

Comment: how else can `f: In => Source[Out, _]` give me a future than to run it?

Comment: You process the invocation to `f` in parallel with `mapAsync(i => Future(f(i)))` and then the resulting Sources get "merged" using `flatMapConcat(identity)`

Comment: `f` just builds the representation of a source. It is not cpu-intensive. It's the running of the source that is heavy and needs to be pipelined.

Comment: @Somatik That is not what your graphics show tho. Not sure how that could be achieved without a Materializer.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with a similar problem. I created a Flow that solves it for me:

```scala
private def parallelFlatMapConcat[I, O](parallelism: Int)(sourceCreator: I => Source[O, NotUsed]) = {
  val mapConcat = Flow[I].flatMapConcat(sourceCreator)

  GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val balance = builder.add(Balance[I](parallelism))
    val merge = builder.add(Merge[O](parallelism))

    for (i ← 0 until parallelism)
      balance.out(i) ~> mapConcat ~> merge.in(i)

    FlowShape(balance.in, merge.out)
  }
}
```

You can then use it as a Flow in the stream. Example usage:

```scala
Source.range(1, 10)
  .via(parallelFlatMapConcat(3)(e => Source.range(1, 5).map(_ * e)))
  .runForeach(println(_))
```

Comment: Are you sure this keeps the ordering?

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a `Flux#flatMapSequential`, which accepts a `maxConcurrency`.
And in Akka stream which will be like:

```scala
      Source(
        List(Source.empty[Int], Source.single(1), Source(List(2, 3, 4)), Source.lazyFuture(() => Future.successful(5))))
        .flatMapConcat(identity, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 129))
        .runWith(toSeq)
        .futureValue should ===(1 to 5)
```